# Post User comment on Web page URL from Native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, comments

I am developing an app in which there is a requirement to Post a comment but the problem is client give me a URL`http://www.wepiku.com/brand/81/140`and this is a Web page URL in which`Web Facebook Plugin`is implemented.

I have tried with native Facebook SDK but not succeeded. I have searched a lot to do this but not succeeded, please anyone know anything regarding this then just let me know. It would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to post comments on external URLs via API.

Comment: @CBroe: Could you please tell me any alternate way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Other than opening the website that embeds the Comments plugin, and let the user post their comment manually via that - nope.